# Correct way to write sql join query for three table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have three tables,
The User table

```
|-----|------|
| id  | email|
|-----|------|
```

The Role table

```
|-----|------|
| id  | name |
|-----|------|
```

And A talble that maintain the relationship of User and Role

```
|----------|---------|
| user_id  | role_id |
|----------|---------|
```

Here the question, if I wanna find out whether a user has a particular role(`ADMIN` for example) or not,
I did something like this:

```
select * from user inner join (user_role innner join role on role.id = user_role.role_id and role.name = 'ADMIN') on user.id = user_role.user_id where user.email = 'xxxx@google.com';
```

When I execute this sql in mysql, it report `Unknown column 'user_role.role_id' in 'on clause'` to me
Why? And what's the correct sql should be ?

Comment: You need `select * from` in that inside query:



select * from user inner join (select * from user_role innner join role on role.id = user_role.role_id and role.name = 'ADMIN') x on user.id = user_role.user_id where user.email = 'xxxx@google.com'

Comment: @chlebek I tried the one you suggested, and now it reports `1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: you need to add that alias `...= 'ADMIN') x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work in your requested case:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    user 
inner join 
    user_role on user.id = user_role.user_id
inner join
    role on user_role.role_id = role.id
where
    role.name = 'ADMIN'
    and user.email = 'xxxx.google.com'
```

You are nesting wrongly your `joins` in your query. That is why the error is thrown. Compare your query with my query above.

Comment: Then the field in table `user_role` must has a different name than `role_id`...

Comment: I know a working one:`select * from user inner join (user_role inner join role on user_role.role_id = role.id) on user.id = user_role.email_id and (role.name = 'ADMIN') where user.email = 'xxx@google.com';`But I dont know why

Comment: My mistake, the column name should be `email_id`, you're right! thx

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are not in the correct position, so outside them the query does not know what 'user_role' is.

Try without parenthesis in the inner join like:

```
select * from user
inner join user_role on user.id = user_role.user_id
inner join role on (role.id = user_role.role_id and role.name = 'ADMIN')
where user.email = 'xxxx@google.com';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I tried, but still gives me the same error `1054 - Unknown column 'user_role.user_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: My mistake, the column name should be email_id, you're right! thx